# Problemas haciendo deploy heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicacion con **react** subida a heroku. Todo estaba funcionando bien, subiendo las actualizaciones a el repo y luego haciendo deploy en heroku pero en la ultima actualizacion modifique un sass de una vista y cuando intente hacer deploy de esa actualizacion me aparecio el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! book_fav_front@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the book_fav_front@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output   above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.QE4lD/_logs/2021-01-30T00_44_28_258Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed

   

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   

   Some possible problems:

   

   - Node version not specified in package.json

     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   

   Love,

   Heroku

   

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

Mi `package.json` es el siguiente:

```
      {
    "name": "book_fav_front",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
      "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
      "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
      "react": "^17.0.1",
      "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
      "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
      "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Podria porque no esta especificada la version de node?

Comment: Estás usando el buildpack de heroku para node o ejecutas alguna instalación por tu cuenta? El packsge-lock está versionado?

Comment: Hola, lo hago desde el mismo heroku todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de ver porque no funcionaba el deploy en **heroku** lo que se hizo fue regresar a una versión anterior del código en mí repo local mediante el comando `git reset --hard comit_hash`  (antes encontrar las versiones anteriores con `git log`)

Luego de eso probé en local y agregué unas cosas más dentro del proyecto, para luego hacer commit y push pero como mí repo local estaba desactualizado con el repo remoto me pidió hacer pull ya que estaba un conmit atrasado. Por lo que aplique pull y volví a hacer push. Luego de eso el deploy corrió perfectamente.